# skip lines in array display

Tags: java, arrays

This program displays a array of `n` rows and `n` columns; where `n` is inputed by the user. The display should be an `n` by `n` array, but in this program is just displays them in one line.

For example if the user enters `3`, the output should be

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Instead with this it displays

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Can someone help me with this? Thanks

```
public class Question2 {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

//Title
    System.out.println("[----------------------]");
    System.out.println("[     Array Pattern    ]");
    System.out.println("[----------------------]");
    System.out.println("");

//declare scanner
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);

//Prompt user to enter a digit greater than or equal to 3
    System.out.println("How many rows/columns do you want your array to have? (Must be at least 3):");

//read user input
    int num = keyboard.nextInt();

//place constraints on int num so that if it is less than 3, the program does not execute
    while(num<3 )
    {
        System.out.println("Lets's try this again....");
        System.out.println("How many rows/colums do you want your array to have? (Must be at least 3):");
        num = keyboard.nextInt();   
    }

    //2D array with number of rows and columns entered by user
    int[][] array = new int [num][num];
    int inc=1;
    for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<array.length;j++)
    {
    array[i][j]=inc;
    inc++;

    }


    //replace all square brackets in array display 
    String a = Arrays.deepToString(array);
    a = a.replace("[", "").replaceAll("]","");

    //replace all commas in array display
    a = a.replace(",", "").replaceAll(",","");
    System.out.println(a);

  }

}
```

Comment: Use loops to display what you want. Don't use Arrays.deepToString and then try to adapt the output to what you want.

Comment: Try to add `a = a.replace("], [", "\n")` after `String a = Arrays.deepToString(array);`

Comment: The addition of \n didn't make a difference to the output

Comment: @CheeseCracker use **loops** instead of `deepToString`. You'll have more control over the output.

Comment: I've just tested this and it works `String a = Arrays.deepToString(arr).replace("], [", "\n").replaceAll("[\\[\\],]", ""); System.out.println(a);` but like @Shashwat said, you should use a loop, this is very unreliable if you try it with a `String` array.

Comment: @JBNizet  I'll take both your comments into consideration but before that can you guide me into the right direction as to how I can create a loop that would break the display at the number desired and continue on the next line?

Comment: Take one minute to think about it. You want a loop that print rows. At the end of each row, you want to go to the next line. For each row, you want to print every value, and not go to the next line after each.

Comment: @Titus This worked, thank you! And I also appreciate everyone helping me with understanding why a loop would be better than strings in this case. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't convert the arrays to strings; that's just more work than is necessary. Instead, loop through the elements, printing each one and then adding a line break after each third element, like so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
    print(i);   // print the number *without* a line break after it

    if (i % 3 == 0) {
        println();    // add a line break after every third element
    } else {
        print(" ");
    }
}

println();
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `Arrays.deepToString`.

Instead, use a nested `for` loop, exactly like in the code that does the `inc++`.

The main idea is like this:

```
foreach row in array:
    print all values
    print a linebreak, via `System.out.println()`
```

And to print all values from a row, you use another `for` loop. In that loop, you can use `System.out.printf("%5d", value)` to print a number and surround it with enough whitespace so that the output looks nicely formatted.

For further hints, see the Rosetta Code example for a multiplication table in Java.